# Magento2 postcode / zipcode length validation and remove waring complete guide

Tags: magento2, checkout, validation

**I am explaining total process in answer section**

Answer (score 0):

In that case we need to work on multiple files.

Firstly we need to add **requirejs-config.js** file into your app/code/**`Vendor/Module`**/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/rules': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/lib/validation/rules': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

And then add your custom rules.js file into **/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/lib/validation/rules.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'moment',
    'Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/utils',
    'mage/translate'
], function ($, _, moment,utils) {
    'use strict';

    return function (validator) {
        var validators = {
            'validate-zip-ch': [
                function (value) {
                   var country_id= jQuery('select[name="country_id"]').val();
                   if(country_id=="CH"){
                       return utils.isEmptyNoTrim(value) || /(^\d{4}$)|(^\d{4}-\d{4}$)/.test(value);
                   }else if(country_id=="DE"){
                     //  return utils.isEmptyNoTrim(value) || /(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{5}$)/.test(value);
                       return true;
                   }else{
                       return true;
                   }
                },
                $.mage.__('The postal code appears to be incorrect. Please enter a four-digit Swiss postcode.')
            ],
        };

        validators = _.mapObject(validators, function (data) {
            return {
                handler: data[0],
                message: data[1]
            };
        });

        return $.extend(validator, validators);
    };
});
```

Important thing is postcode length is very country to country, here I handle this conditions, and also added custom message which I will manipulate language by csv files

**$.mage.__('The postal code appears to be incorrect. Please enter a four-digit Swiss postcode.')**

Finally I added this into the checkout_index_index.xml

```
<item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">70</item>
    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="validate-zip-ch" xsi:type="string">true</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

Now I  remove warning message, for this I also add the zip_codes.xml to the
**/app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/zip_codes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Directory:etc/zip_codes.xsd">

    <zip countryCode="CH">
        <codes>
            <code id="pattern_1" active="false" example="1234">^[0-9]{4}$</code>
        </codes>
    </zip>

</config>
```

Finally i added to translation into de_CH.csv file.

```
"The postal code appears to be incorrect. Please enter a four-digit Swiss postcode.","Die Postleitzahl scheint falsch zu sein. Bitte geben Sie eine vierstellige Schweizer Postleitzahl ein."
```

[image]

github: https://github.com/khasru/magento2_postcode_length_validation/tree/main